# How to POST the data to AWS API gateway from my flutter app?

Tags: amazon-web-services, api, flutter, aws-api-gateway

How to call the API from Flutter app and post the data like name of the person to API from Flutter app. I have created an AWS API gateway which stores the data to my S3 bucket. I need to pass the data from my Flutter app to the API. Please can anyone help me out with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AWS has announced a developer preview of AWS Amplify Flutter. It's not production-ready yet and it only contains auth, storage, and analytics for now. Check it out.

Here are the details: [AWS Amplify Flutter](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mobile/announcing-aws-amplify-flutter-developer-preview/)

Also, there is a community plugin that works perfectly fine on IOS and Android with Cognito and Sigv4 to access all AWS services securely.

Here are the details: [Amazon Cognito Identity Dart](https://pub.dev/packages/amazon_cognito_identity_dart_2)

Comment: What about scenarios where you can't use AWS Amplify, such as AWS in China? Amplify is not supported in either of the AWS China regions.

Comment: I would definitely recommend using community plugin ```amazon_cognito_identity_dart_2``` over Amplify for now